# Why doesn't Ego know that Groot is by his brain/core?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, guardians-of-the-galaxy-vol-2

In *Guardians of the Galaxy Vol.2* near the end of the movie we see

> Groot (being the smallest) going to the core/brain of Ego to place a bomb and kill him.

Why doesn't Ego (being a whole planet) know/feel/realize that Groot is getting inside of him and trying to hurt him?

Comment: I think he does know, because when the timer is down to 26 seconds he screams _"We need to stop it!"_ and tries to get to the bomb. But Peter stops him and throws him to the ground. - What I'm wondering is why Ego didn't use one of his tentacles to move the bomb away from his brain.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Ego isn't omniscient...he has limitations.

Mantis says that it will take Ego time to realise there are; then when he does find them he's put to sleep for a while and then there's a whole "space battle" going on inside the planet causing immense damage.

He's also trying to control Peter at the same time while the other Guardians are also running around

So, he's distracted and has no reason to know that there is a tiny plant running around inside him and even if he could he has no reason to suspect that it that could cause him damage.

However, we do see Groot being crushed inside the tiny tunnels...so it's possible that Ego *does* know he's there...but again, what damage could a tiny plant do?

[image]

Comment: Well, I don't know, maybe plant a BOMB :) Jokes aside good point on distraction.

Comment: "Mantis says that it will take Ego time to realise there are" you meant "Mantis says that it will take Ego time to realise they are there" ?

Answer (score 4):

Probably for the same reason that you would not be able to feel internal parasites within your own body.  There simply may not be nerves or sensory organs in or around the area where Baby Groot is.

Comment: I thought the same but then I remembered that *he was able* to locate them as a group when they were inside of him.

Comment: I think a group of people would be much easier to detect than a single small being.  That and his focus at that time was on finding the group, or more specifically his son. Much different than being able to detect a small plant you aren't actively looking for.

Comment: I think it was the only place the group could be in, so he did not have to look hard...